# How to auto populate select option through ajax from json data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my controller I have the code:

```
         <?php
        class Cat_cntrl extends CI_controller{


            public function __construct(){
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('cat_model');
                $this->load->helper('form','url');

            }

            public function index(){
                    $get=$this->cat_model->fetchcatdata();
                    $data['result']=$get;
                   $this->load->view('cat_view',$data);

                    }
            public function subcatselect(){

                $cate=$this->input->post('cate');
                $get=$this->cat_model->getsubo($cate);
                $data['result']=$get;
                 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$data['result']));
            }


           }

        ?>
```

in model I've code:

```
     <?php
    class Cat_model extends CI_model{
        public function fetchcatdata(){ 
        $this->db->select()->from('cat');
            $query=$this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
        }
        }
        public function getsubo($cate){
            $this->db->select($cate)->from('sub_cat');
            $query=$this->db->get();
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
        }
        }
    }
```

In view the code i have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td><select id="cate">
            <option>
                None Selected
            </option>   
            <?php foreach ($result as $value) {
                ?>
                <option id="val">
                    <?php echo $value->category; ?>
                </option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sub Category</td>
            <td><select id="myselect">

            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="" id="sub">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sub').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        var cate=$( "#cate option:selected").val();
        var url="<?php echo base_url();?>cat_cntrl/subcatselect";
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:url,
            data:{cate :cate},
            success:function(response){ 

        }
        })
    })
        })
</script>
```

The problem is how to auto populate the select through ajax in this code. What to use after success function? I'm not getting exact answer from Google for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your success function your just have to loop through array which you receive as response and append `option` to `select`

```
$("#your_select_id").append($('<option>', {
   value: 'somevalue',
    text: 'some text'
}));
```

For example something like below

```
dataType: "json",
success:function(response){ 
    $.each(response.result,function(i, item){
         $("#myselect").append($('<option>', {
               value: item[cate],  
               text: item[cate]     
         }));
    });
}
```

Say if your response json looks like below, below should work, you have to decide how you send data to browser and manipulate it, below one is example for your to start with, on click it creates dropdown option, same way you can implement with ajax

```js
var response = {
  result: [{
      value: 'val1',
      text: 'text1'
    },
    {
      value: 'val2',
      text: 'text2'
    }

  ]
}
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $.each(response.result, function(i, item) {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
      value: item.value,
      text: item.text
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect"></select>
<input type="button" value="click me to create option" id="btn" />
```

Also value attribute is missing

```
<?php foreach ($result as $value):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value->category; ?>">
          <?php echo $value->category; ?>
      </option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: @nisha I modified my post and added one example also to you to start from scratch